# how can i access the history in my react components from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i'm trying  to get the history object from the props in the component i'm working on and it always prints an error this is the class i'm trying to use history object in it

```
import React from 'react';

const Admin = (props) => {
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Admin</h1>  
        <button 
        onClick={()=>this.props.history.push("/edit/new")}
        type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-1">
            Add
        </button>
        <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>   
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.prod.map(prod1 =>(
                        <tr key ={prod1.id}>
                            <td>{prod1.name}</td>
                            <td>{prod1.price}</td>
                            <td>                                   
                                <i 
                                onClick={()=>this.props.history.push(`/edit/${prod1.id}`)
                                }
                                className="fas fa-edit"></i>
                       
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span onClick={()=>props.delete(prod1)}>                        
                                    <i className ="fas fa-trash  m-2" ></i>
                                </span>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> 
                    ))}
               
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>






    </React.Fragment>
);
```

}

export default Admin;

and the app.jsx i called it in route like this

```
                            <Route path="/admin" element = {<Admin
                        prod = {this.state.Product}
                        delete={this.deleteEntery}
                        editing = {this.editElement}
                        />}/>
```

Comment: can you share the error and which version of react router you are using?

Comment: it's not error it gives me undefined object and the react version is 17.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported useHistory hook and declared history using it.

Add this to import:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
```

call useHistory history inside your function using variable history:

```
const history = useHistory()
```

If you have any import error, then use latest React version as well as install 'react-router-dom' v5.2.0 by using this command: `npm install 'react-router-dom@v5.2.0'`

Comment: Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
 i get this error

Comment: If you must stick to the latest react-router-dom v6.0.0, then replace useHistory with useNavigate. Else, downgrade your react-router-dom to v5.2.0 and your code works as it should.

Comment: react version is 17.0.2  this is the version i work with so would i down grade it ?

Comment: No need to downgrade. Just check your react-router-dom version. If it is V6.0.0 then replace useHistory with useNavigate or downgrade react-router-dom to V5.2.0 and useHistory will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are not passing 'history' as a prop to Admin component, if you wanted to use history object in your component you would simply need to import it and use it (No need to pass it as prop).

```
// Import it at the top of your file
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

// Call this hook inside your functional component, history variable has all the required properties
const history = useHistory()
```

Comment: Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. i get this error

Comment: You need to be using React >= 16.8 in order to use any of these hooks!

-useHistory
-useLocation
-useParams
-useRouteMatch

Comment: react version is 17.0.2  this is the version i work with so would i down grade it ?